# How to update a specific index in jquery each function?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this function to update all images:

```
setInterval(function(){

                    console.log($( ".image" ));

                    $( ".image" ).each(function( index ) {

                        console.log(index);

                        base_url = $(this).attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
                        address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
                        $(this).attr("src", address);

                    });                     
                },1000);
```

This is used in a primefaces p:graphicImage:

```
            <ui:repeat value="#{imgController.imgList}" var="images">
                <p:graphicImage id="pic" class="image" url="#{images.img}?rand=0" width="360px">

                </p:graphicImage>
                <p:draggable for="pic" />
            </ui:repeat>
```

The console.log return for me this:

```
 0 image.xhtml?imgId=300335:31
 1 image.xhtml?imgId=300335:31
 2 image.xhtml?imgId=300335:31
 3 image.xhtml?imgId=300335:31
```

Thats my doubt, if I want instead update all images, is there a way to pass an specific index for:

```
 each(function( index )
```

Example:

```
 each(function( 3 )
```

If I just want update the third image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I just want update the third image ?

If you just want to update the third image, you can use `.eq(3)` to retrieve just the third image like this:

```
$(".image").eq(2).attr("src", adddress);
```

Or, including the rest of your logic:

```
var img = $(".image").eq(2);
var base_url = img.attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
var address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
img.attr("src", address);
```

And, here's a working snippet that changes the `.src` of the third image and then logs the resulting `.src` properties:

```js
var img = $(".image").eq(2);
var base_url = img.attr('src').split('?rand=')[0];
var address = base_url + '?rand=' + Math.random();
img.attr("src", address);

// log output
$(".image").each(function() {
   log(this.src);
});

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/0000FF/FFFFFF.jpg&text=Test?rand=1.23456789">
<img class="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/0000FF/FFFFFF.jpg&text=Test?rand=1.23456789">
<img class="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/0000FF/FFFFFF.jpg&text=Test?rand=1.23456789">
<img class="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/0000FF/FFFFFF.jpg&text=Test?rand=1.23456789">
```

Comment: I´m getting this error TypeError: img.attr is not a function

Comment: @EdsonCezar - If jQuery is properly installed as `$`, you should not get that error.  You can see it working in the snippet I added to my answer.